# How to increase the number of pdf files firefox/thunderbird can open

Tags: firefox, browser, pdf, thunderbird

I'd like to know if there is a setting that limits the number of PDF files which can be open at any point in time in the firefox or thunderbird browser. I have a large amount of PDF open in my browser and I like it. The problem is, after I open 20 (more or less) PDFs' , the browser would not open any more PDF files and I have to load it in a PDF reader or save on the disk.

I hope there is option in about:config but I do not find it.
Any suggestion ?

Comment: In what capacity would Firefox refuse to open more PDFs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to about:config (type `about:config` in Firefox's address bar and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>).
2. Change the value of `dom.workers.maxPerDomain` to something bigger, e.g. 50. I tried 25 and it worked, but I don't see why a bigger value wouldn't also work.
3. Restart Firefox.

[Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/3lxjdn/unable_to_open_more_than_20_pdf_files/cvawrst)

Note: I don't know whether changing the above-mentioned value has any other effects.